# [USART - STM32F4xx]: How to wait until character arrives on Status Register (USART_SR)?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, stm32f4

I'm trying to realize a USART2_RX on a [STM32F411VET](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f411ve.html).

During a video tutorial, I saw that the teacher use these statements to read data in data register:

```
char USART2_read(void){
  while(!(USART2->SR & 0x0020)) {}
  return USART2->DR;
}
```

Specifically, he uses

```
while(!(USART2->SR & 0x0020)){}
```

to wait a char. But observing the [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/9b/53/39/1c/f7/01/4a/79/DM00119316.pdf/files/DM00119316.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00119316.pdf), it seems that the status register (USART_SR) is 0x0C0... in its reset form, so...

Why we check that value (i.e., 0x0020)?

Comment: what libraries are you using? `SR` and `DR` are not from the HAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `while` loop you are waiting for the "Read data register not empty" bit to be set. This is bit number 5 and `1 << 5` is equal to `0x0020`. You could equally have written:

```
 while(!(USART2->SR & (1 << 5)) {}
```

Comment: Ok sure, but in order to check that bit, he should set `RXNEIE=1` in the USART_CR1 register, but he didn't. I'm right?

Comment: No, I Think the user26etc. in the 2nd answer read the situation well: "RXNEIE should be set for generation of interrupt. But he doesn't use interrupts. He usess polling method."

Answer (score 2):

He checks 0x20 because it is the RXNE (RX not empty) bit in Status Register.
He checks the bit5(RXNE) - not the value 0x20.

Comment: Ok sure, but in order to check that bit, he should set `RXNEIE=1` in the USART_CR1 register, but he didn't. I'm right?

Comment: No, RXNEIE should be set for generation of interrupt. But he doesn't use interrupts. He usess polling method.